# Equal maximum and minimum in a large-scale linear programming

Tags: integration, calculus-of-variations, linear-programming

For a linear optimization of an integral (with integral constraints), I perform a linear programming for the equivalent series. Maximum and minimum of the LP problem tend to be equal as I increase the number of variables.

---

Does it necessarily mean that there is a unique feasible solution? If yes, it means that the value of the integral is obtained from the constraints analytically, isn't it?
Example: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/457500/88652

Comment: it's not 100% clear what you are solving for. Your $p(x)$ actually depends on $f(x)$ and $C$, isn't it?

Comment: Of course it depends on them, so does the integral extrema. But, regardless of the $f(x)$ and $C$, the extrema estimated by LP tend to each other. I have tested it for different $f(x)$ and $C$, with only the conditions mentioned in the example. A very interesting point which may help you: the ratio of maximum to minimum for an arbitrary $f(x)$, is very near to one, except for the values near $C=0$ wherein there is a very high pick.

Comment: Are you saying that when $C$ is small then the values of maxima and minima are rather different?

Comment: Yes Dima, I do not claim that the maximum and minimum are exactly the same. But the ratio of them is very close to one, an asymptote a bit larger than one. This ratio get further from the asymptote as we approach $C=0$, where this ratio is exactly one because $p(x)=0$. There is a discontinuity of the ratio at $C=0$.

Comment: Do you suggest any other method except LP for solving the problem?

Comment: I can only say that it's very unlikely that there is unique feasible point (a probability measure on $[0,a]$). It's just they all give you roughly the same maxima and minima.

Comment: there is also a dependence on $C$: e.g. if $\max_{0\leq x\leq a} f(x)$ is less than $C$ then your problem becomes infeasible. The further $C$ is from this maximum, the bigger the feasibility region.